Trapping your nemesis on a circular track
Inspired by Getting lost on a Circular Track.
You are in possession of a very peculiar circular track. No matter how nice of a day it is, the track is always covered in an extremely thick fog which prevents anyone on it from seeing the exit unless they stop moving exactly in line with it. Also, while you're not exactly sure how the magic works, when people try to walk along the track, you can control the direction (though they still control the distance). Additionally, you always know how many steps someone is going to take, before making that decision.
You have managed to convince your nemesis (a perfectly competent logician, save for his penchant for being caught in contrived and unrealistic mathematical traps) not only to enter your track, but also to then walk a certain distance x in some direction, for your choice of any value of x.
Can you ensure that he never escapes?
With mathematical specificity:

The track is a perfect (Euclidean) circle of known radius.
The exit is a single point on the circle.
Your nemesis starts at a point somewhere on that circle, at a distance $x$ away from the exit.
You choose the value of x, but your nemesis knows what you chose.
At every point in time they choose to move any (perfectly precise) distance in a single direction on the track, then you may choose whether their movement is clockwise or counterclockwise.
You win if you can come up with a strategy such that no sequence of moves will ever allow them to reach the exit.


Unless I'm missing something, rot13(guvf frrzf vqragvpny gb gur obahf gnfx bs gur yvaxrq dhrfgvba: enaqbz zbirzrag vf rssrpgviryl rdhvinyrag gb znyvpvbhf zbirzrag, fb gur frg bs cbvagf sebz juvpu  lbhe arzrfvf pna rfpncr vf fgvyy gur qlnqvp engvbanyf naq lbh pna jva ol chggvat gurz ba nalguvat bhgfvqr bs gubfr r.t. bar guveq bs gur jnl ebhaq)

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/128287/83557 ?

@emanresuA - The difference is that your nemesis knows how far they start from the exit. This puzzle is to either figure out how they can use that information, or prove that that information doesn't help them.

Indeed your nemesis has this insteresting information. However the answer given to the other problem still applies and solves this one.

rot13(Yrg k or na veengvbany ahzore. Gura znxr fher ur arire ernpurf nal rqtr bs frtzragf bs pvephzsrerapr/2^k.)
